# Updating a ListItem that another user has edited

Tags: splistitem

I have an event receiver that creates/updates/deletes publishing pages in a publishing library.

In `ItemUpdating`, I get a handle to the page's underlying `ListItem`, change some of its properties and then update it.  Finally I update the page, publish, and approve it.

```
var listItem = defaultPage.GetListItem();
defaultPage.CheckOut();
listItem[someField] = someValue; 
listItem.Update();
defaultPage.Update();

defaultPage.CheckIn("Checked in on update.");
defaultPage.Publish("Published on update.");
defaultPage.Approve("Approved on update.");
```

This all works great when the page status is `Published` - I determine that by checking the value of `listItem.File.Level`.

There are three other scenarios that I need to work with:

**1. The page is checked out, but not changed or saved back.**

If the user checked out the page but didn't make any changes, I can call `defaultPage.UndoCheckOut();` and continue on. In this case, Level is `SPFileLevel.Checkout`.

**2. The user checked out the page, made some changes, saved them, but didn't check the page back in**

If the user checked out the page, made some changes and saved them, Level is still `SPFileLevel.Checkout`, but the call to `listItem.Update();` fails with the following exception.

> The file Pages/default.aspx has been
>   modified by DOMAIN\User

**3. The user checked the page back in after making changes.**
Here, Level is `SPFileLevel.Draft`, I can simply check out the file and do what I need to do.

Any thoughts on getting around the issue in #2?

Comment: Can't you just force `CheckIn` and then proceed as normal with the `Update`?

Comment: Kit, had a typo in the last sentence (fixed). The one that I need help with is when another user has checked in changes. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any issue with #3? First, you'll have to validate if it is checked out by another user.. yes? then force check in. Then, proceed with your check out and update.

Comment: Kit, I tried that and saw that the error happens even when I check the other user's changes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that after you check-in the other user's changes, you need to get an updated instance of the SPListItem, and then call listItem.Update() on *that* instance. I've seen this error before when SharePoint detects that the item you are trying to commit to the database is an older version than the one that is currently committed.

Comment: Jason, is this the right sequence?  Check in the other user's changes, get an updated listitem, make my changes, update?

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right. Did you get a chance to try this?

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution for the #2:

Before `"listItem.Update()"` insert `"properties.InvalidateListItem()"`